# Get Extension attributes from \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface via Quote

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I have a subscribe at checkout checkbox that subscribes customers to newsletters at checkout if a checkbox is checked however having issues with some custom payment methods.

Most payment methods are fine and plugins fire for `SavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` function. In the original function an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface` is passed and value for checkbox can be pulled from Extension Attributes like below:

```
public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {

    if ($paymentMethod->getExtensionAttributes() &&
        $paymentMethod->getExtensionAttributes()->getSubscribeAtCheckout()
    ) {
        $this->subscriber->subscribe($email);
    }
}
```

I however need to do similar to a similar method in another module where above plugin does not fire. Have created a plugin for a similar function that fires when creating order with this custom payment method. This however does not have the same parameters and am hoping to access the **extension attributes** without the `PaymentInterface` being passed like in the original function. Something like below:

```
public function afterSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    \Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Model\PiRequestManagement $subject,
    $result,
    $cartId,
    PiDataRequest $requestData
) {
    $quote = $subject->getQuoteById($cartId);
    $payment = $quote->geyPayment();
            
    if ($payment->getExtensionAttributes() &&
        $payment->getExtensionAttributes()->getSubscribeAtCheckout()
    ) {
        $this->subscriber->subscribe($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Have looked around everywhere for access to this value but `getPayment()` just pulls an instance of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment` and the value does not seem to be available with `getExtensionAttributes()` from there.

**Extension attributes** seem to be set for `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface` via `extension_attributes.xml` and hoping there is a simple way of accessing this via **quote**?

Failing that would want to set the checkbox's value to somewhere within quote so that it is accessible. Currently only reference to this data being set seems to be below mixin for place order:

```
define([
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Swissup_SubscribeAtCheckout/js/model/data-assigner'
], function (wrapper, dataAssigner) {
    'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(
            placeOrderAction,
            function (originalAction, paymentData, messageContainer) {
                dataAssigner(paymentData);

                return originalAction(paymentData, messageContainer);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

That sets the values based on the paths of the form elements within checkout:

```
define([
    'uiRegistry'
], function (registry) {
    'use strict';

    return function (paymentData) {
        var paths = [
            'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.before-form.subscribe-at-checkout',
            'checkout.steps.billing-step.payment.beforeMethods.subscribe-at-checkout'
        ];

        paths.forEach(function (path) {
            registry.get(path, function (component) {
                //jscs:disable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
                if (!paymentData.extension_attributes) {
                    paymentData.extension_attributes = {};
                }

                paymentData.extension_attributes.swissup_subscribe_at_checkout = component.checked();
                //jscs:enable requireCamelCaseOrUpperCaseIdentifiers
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Maybe there is another way of doing above that can set that value somewhere I can pull it from quote?

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this?